# JPA, delete entity when a child entity is deleted

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following entity:

```
  @Data
  @Entity
  public class DailyEntry {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private Project project;

  // more fields
}
```

I want `DailyEntry` to be deleted whenever its `project` is deleted. `Project` doenst have `DailyEntry` as a property, so i cant put a cascade on delete annotation there. Is there something like cascade which works in the other direction? I need an annotation which does the following: `If one of my fields(project) is deleted, delete me too`. Does an annotation like this exist or do i have to manually implement the logic in my delete method?

Comment: I think you must manually implement the logic.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define in Project entity the relationship with a list of DailyEntry, and mark it as orphanRemoval = true.

This way:
 @OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)
 private List dailyEntries;

Comment: orphans are entities which dont have parents, but he wants to delete that parent which has no child